# Grey large text behind typed text on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-reader

This is a picture of my issue.
The larger, more faded text behind the smaller text is what I'm trying to get rid of.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

What application are you running? It is probably a setting in that application....